# Paste RTF text using clipboard is not working if I send appointment without displaying it in code

Tags: c#, outlook

I am developing an application in visual studio 2010 and c sharp. In this application, I am creating an appointment item, pasting some RTF text in the appointment body via word doc and sending it. Following is a part of my code:

```
  public void SetAppointmentBodyViaWordDoc(ref Outlook.AppointmentItem appointment, string rtfText)
```

{
           Outlook.Inspector inspector = null;
            try
            {
                //appointment.Body = string.Empty;
                System.Windows.Forms.DataObject dataObject = new   System.Windows.Forms.DataObject();
                dataObject.SetData(DataFormats.Rtf, rtfText);
                System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.Clear();
                System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObject, false, 10, 200);
                inspector = appointment.GetInspector;
                Word.Document appointmentItemDocument = inspector.WordEditor as Word.Document;
                appointmentItemDocument.Application.ScreenUpdating = false;
                foreach (Word.Window window in appointmentItemDocument.Windows)
                {
                    window.Selection.WholeStory();
                    window.Selection.TypeBackspace();
                    window.Selection.Paste();

```
                //move the cursor to the top
                object story = Word.WdUnits.wdStory;
                object missing = Missing.Value;
                window.Selection.HomeKey(ref story, ref missing);
                break;
            }
            appointmentItemDocument.Application.ScreenUpdating = true;
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Exception in SetAppointmentBodyViaWordDoc(): " + System.Environment.NewLine +
                    ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            if (inspector != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(inspector);
        }
```

}

When I call appointment.Display() then it works perfectly and I can see and send the appointment with the pasted text. But if I send appointment in Code using appointment.Send() method without displaying the appointment then it carry no pasted text in body and recipient gets empty body. I need to send it without displaying the appointment. Please let me know if anyone have any idea regarding this issue.

Thank you very much,

Surya

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply set the AppointmeentItem.RtfBody property?

Comment: Hello Dmitry, setting byte array to the AppointmeentItem.RtfBody is not working in outlook 2007 while it is fine in outlook 2010. That's why I am using inspector to paste the content in appointment body. However, it is not throwing any  exception with word doc but not able to send content as well.

Comment: I think they (MS) had a problem with setting RtfBody using late binding; early binding should be fine. Of course you can also use Redemption (http://www.dimastr.com/redemption), which exposes RtfBody property on both Safe*Item objects and RDOMail object and its decendants.